# Regular expression to match a text with new line at the end

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a Regex that matches only if there is a new line (\n) at the end of a text. It doesn't matter how many lines I have the last one should be ended with a new line.

For example,

```
TEXT1 = "This is a text without a new line at the end" failed to match
TEXT2 = "This is a text with a new line at the end\n" success to match
TEXT3 = "This is a \n text with multiple lines" failed to match
TEXT4 = "This is a \n text with multiple lines\n a new line at the end\n" success to match
```

I cam with the following regex but it doesn't work as I expected:

```
^((.)*(\r\n|\r|\n)*)*(\r\n|\r|\n)+$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [String.endsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-):

```
"abc\n".endsWith("\n")  // true
```

Or with [Matcher.find](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--):

```
Pattern.compile("\\n$").matcher("abc\n").find();  // true
```

If you want your regex to match the entire string from start to end, you can use the [Pattern.DOTALL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag to change the behavior of the dot expression (`.`) to match any character *including* newlines. DOTALL can be specified with an embedded flag `(?s)` or as an option to [Pattern.compile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-int-):

```
"abc\n".matches("(?s)^.*\\n$")  // true

Pattern.compile("^.*\\n$", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher("abc\n").matches(); // true
```